# Отмена hover и click элемента навигации при ресайзе

Tags: jquery

Есть такая навигация:

```js
$('.trigger-navigation').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var
  $this  = $(this),
      nav = $this.closest('.page-nav'),
      inner = nav.find('.wrap');

  inner.slideToggle();
});

$(window).on('load resize', function() {


    if($(window).width() >= 500){

        $('.page-nav .wrap').slideDown();


        $('.page-nav__item').hover(
            function() { 
                var
                    $this  = $(this),
                    subMenu = $this.find('.page-nav__sub'),
                    wrap = $this.closest('.page-nav__list');


                $this.addClass('hover').siblings().removeClass('hover');

                subMenu.stop(true,true).slideDown(100);

                subMenu.css({
                    left: $this.position().left
                });
            }, 
            function() {
                var
                    $this  = $(this),
                    subMenu = $this.find('.page-nav__sub'),
                    wrap = $this.closest('.page-nav__list');

                $this.removeClass('hover');

                subMenu.stop(true,true).slideUp(100);
            }
        );

    } else if($(window).width() < 500){
        $('.page-nav__item').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        //$('.page-nav__item').removeClass('hover');

        $('.page-nav__item').on('click', function(){
            var 
                $this = $(this),
                subMenu = $this.find('.page-nav__sub'),
                wrap = $this.closest('.page-nav__list');

            if(!$this.hasClass('hover')){
                $this.addClass('hover');
                subMenu.stop(true,true).slideDown(100);
            } else {
                $this.removeClass('hover');
                subMenu.stop(true,true).slideUp(100);
            }
            
        });
    }    
    
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


.page-nav__sub {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    width: auto;
    display: none;
}

.page-nav__item {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    width: 14%;
}

.page-nav__list {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.page-nav__link {
   font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 0 12px;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

.page-nav {
    background: red;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.trigger-navigation {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .page-nav__item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .page-nav__sub {
    position: relative;
    left: 0 !important;
  }
  
  .trigger-navigation {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .page-nav .wrap {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .page-nav .wrap {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

  
  <nav class="page-nav">
    <a href="#" class="trigger-navigation"></a>
    
    <div class="wrap">
      <ul class="page-nav__list">
        <li class="page-nav__item">
          <a href="#" class="page-nav__link">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        
        <li class="page-nav__item">
          <span class="page-nav__link">Item 2</span>
          
          <ul class="page-nav__sub">
            <li>
              Lorem ipsum.
            </li>
            <li>
              Dolor sit amet.
            </li>
            <li>
              Sit amet. 
            </li>
            <li>
              Consectetur adipisicing
            </li>
            <li>
              Corporis, soluta.
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li class="page-nav__item">
          <span class="page-nav__link">Item 3</span>
          
          <ul class="page-nav__sub">
            <li>
              Lorem ipsum.
            </li>
            <li>
              Dolor sit amet.
            </li>
            <li>
              Sit amet. 
            </li>
            <li>
              Consectetur adipisicing
            </li>
            <li>
              Corporis, soluta.
            </li>
            <li>
              Lorem ipsum.
            </li>
            <li>
              Dolor sit amet.
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li class="page-nav__item">
          <span class="page-nav__link">Item 4</span>
          
          <ul class="page-nav__sub">
            <li>
              Lorem ipsum.
            </li>
            <li>
              Dolor sit amet.
            </li>
            <li>
              Sit amet. 
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

На десктопах, при наведении на ссылку, должен срабатывать только `hover` (реализованный именно с помощью jquery, а не css), а на мобильных девайсах, подменю должно появляться только при клике (`hover` отменяется).

Все срабатывает до момента с кнопкой тригера, по клику на которую все меню скрывается\раскрывается.

При мобильном разрешении (к примеру меньше 500px)после клика на раскрыть меню, клик на пункт меню не срабатывает - дергается, класс `.hover` моментально присваивается и исчезает, подменю, соотвтетственно, не  раскрывается.

**Вопрос:** Как граммотно реализовать такое меню?

На десктопе всю меню `display: block`, при наведении на пункты меню - подменю плавно появляется\исчезает.

На мобильных девайсах все меню появляется\исчезает только по клику на `.trigger-navigation`, при **клике** (ховер отменяется) на пункт меню - плавно появляется\исчезает подменю.

**P.S:** реализация полностью с помощью jquery (не css).

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/soyisag/edit?js,output)